# Returning the distinct/unique values in a column in Excel and make the table expand

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a column that looks something like this:

[4,5,6,4,4,4,4,5,6,7]

I want to return the distinct values in a table column like this:

[4,5,6,7]

The problem is if i add an 8 to the first column:

[4,5,6,4,4,4,4,5,6,8]

Then I needed it to return:
 [4,5,6,7,8]

I need the table to expand. In other words, it needs to update by itself.

I tried using Data --> Advanced. But is does not expand the table and needs to be updated manually.

Any tips?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Pivot tables???

Comment: I tried that, but I'm not able to sort it my unique number. Im only able to calculate sum, average etc

Comment: Maybe with a VBA Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following, in B1 write =A1, in B2 write:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$1000, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$1:B1, $A$1:$A$1000), 0)), "")
```

Array Formula press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time and drag it down
You can drag it more than needed in that case whenever you add Data it will show
Also for $A$1:$A$1000 you can write instead of 1000 more than the maximum rows number

Answer (score 0):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=A1
```

In **B2** enter the **array formula**:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$1000,INT(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,$A$1:$A$1000)=0,ROW($A$1:$A$1000)+(COLUMN($A$1:$A$1000)*0.01)),1)),100*MOD(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,$A$1:$A$1000)=0,ROW($A$1:$A$1000)+(COLUMN($A$1:$A$1000)*0.01)),1),1)),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

See:

[Coderre Formula](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-excel/extract-unique-data-from-table/1ba1796a-c647-e011-9575-d8d385dcbb12)